# Sending a blank value from html form webpart to excel web access webpart

Tags: 2010, excel-web-access-webpart, html-form-web-part

On a SharePoint 2010 page,

1. I have HTML form web part that has a simple text box control and
2. Excel Web Access webpart that shows an excel that too has a name(defined name) and defined as parameters in Excel and
3. Html form webpart is connected to send the text box control's value to Excel web access webpart.

Now with this setup, I am able to change values in a text box and on HTML form submit, that value is passed to EWA and I can see that on the page.

But the problem is if I remove the value(read blank text box) and submit HTML form, I don't see the blank value is being passed. I still see the old value passed by the user.

If a user removes a value and submits, I want the cell in the excel also should be empty.

I tried sending `null`, `#Value`! nothing worked.

Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `HTML form web part` that has a simple text box control for a filtering purpose only so I suggest to you use `Text Filter Web Part` that you can send empty or blank strings to your Excel Web Access web part.

- Go to your page > Edit it > Add Web Part > Filter Category > `Text Filter Web Part`

[image]

If you are missing  `Text Filter Web Part` , activate `SharePoint Server Enterprise Site Collection features` at `Site Collection Features`.

Comment: I can't use Text filter web part, because I want to pass around 20 values to excel and excel uses those values to do calcualations(read macros, stuff etc) and updates charts inside that excel. So html form webpart is what I need :(